# Can we make Widget Options validaton in magento?

Tags: php, magento, widget

If we add back end configurations in file system.xml, we can add validation to every field using validate tag like the following:

```
<duration>
   <label> ...</label>
   <frontend_type >text</frontend_type>
   <validate>required-entry validate-number</validate>
   <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
   <sort_order>70</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</duration>
```

My question is the there similar way to make the same to widget options in magento?
For example like this in widget.xml file:

```
<widget type="common/widget">
        <name>new widget</name>
        <description>new widget</description>
        <parameters>
            <template>
                <visible>0</visible>
                <value>template.phtml</value>
            </template>
            <after translate="label">
                <visible>1</visible>
                <label>...</label>
                <type>text</type>
                <validate>required-entry validate-number</validate>
            </after>
</parameters>
</widget>
```

Comment: No one knows if that's possible? O_O

Comment: It seems someone asked the same question in Magento forum and linked to this question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65189/can-we-make-widget-options-validaton-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this directly via XML. However, you can create a custom block, set the validation css class there, and use it as the type in widget.xml.

app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/widget.xml:

```
<somefield>
    <required>1</required>
    <visible>1</visible>
    <label>Some number</label>
    <type>mynamespace_mymodule/element_numeric</type>
</somefield>
```

app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Element/Numeric.php:

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Element_Numeric extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $element->setType('text');
        $element->addClass('validate-digits');
        parent::render($element);
    }
}
```

It is important that the custom element block extend the class **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element** so that it will display properly in the fieldset.

Answer (score 1):

@Joe Mizzi method render should return a value

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Element_Numeric extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Renderer_Fieldset_Element
{
    public function render(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract $element)
    {
        $element->setType('text');
        $element->addClass('validate-digits');
        return parent::render($element);
    }
}
```